# replace yarn version v1.0.0 to v0.28.4

Tags: yarnpkg

I currently used nightly builds to update my yarn and I'm using yarn v1.0.0-20170906.0822.

But it had a serious problem which is blocking deployment on Heroku.

So, I searched a way to migrate from v1.0.0xx to v0.28.4.

I tried to remove it using `brew uninstall yarn` however it failed to delete yarn so I can still v1.0.0xx shown when I hit `yarn --version` on the terminal.

I remember I installed yarn via brew, not npm.

Are there any other options to delete yarn and replace it with v0.28.4?

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `switch` subcommand:

```
brew switch yarn 0.28.4
```

Comment: $ brew switch yarn 0.28.4
Error: yarn does not have a version "0.28.4" in the Cellar.
Versions available: 0.27.5_1

Terminal emits this message. I think it's because 0.27.5_1 version of Yarn is newest among stable versions. Have another idea to that?